# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: - 1

Tags: java, loops

Tengo el siguiente error al querer leer contenido de un archivo .txt y compararlo con el contenido de un ArrayList lo cual hago:

```
public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        try {
            // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("ruta.txt"));
            // Creamos el objeto de entrada
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
            String contenido;
            // Leer el archivo linea por linea
            while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                  String[] arrayStrings = contenido.split(",");
                  String[] array = arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayStrings.length - 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
                        if (arrayStrings[i].substring(0, arrayStrings[i].lastIndexOf(",")).equals(array[j].substring(0, array[j].lastIndexOf(",")))) {
                            System.out.println("Contedodo: "+arrayStrings[i]+"     Contenido array: "+array[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
//                 Imprimimos la línea por pantalla
//                System.out.println(contenido);
            }
            // Cerramos el archivo
            entrada.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

El contenido del archivo .txt es el siguiente:

**25,SAN SALVADOR**

**45,SAN MIGUEL**

**32,SAN JERONIMO**

**20,BUENOS AIRES**

El contenido del array es:

**PDA25_20171022164520**

**PDA45_20171022164520**

**PDA35_20171022164520**

**PDA55_20171022164520**

Donde quiero buscar el código de dos dígitos del archivo .txt y compararlo con el que hay en el array pero no logro hacerlo. El primer problema que tengo es la Exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:-1` y el otro problema es que no se como compararlos, es decir, que busque el código en el archivo .txt y lo compare con el que hay dentro del array, mostrando a que provincia corresponde cada código, me explico.. algún ej que me ayude? Desde ya gracias.

Comment: creo que la estrategia que estas siguiendo no es la mejor esto por que por cada registro del archivo tienes que recorrer el arrayList, a parte que por cada registro del archivo haces un split. Puedes hacer recibir el arraList recorrerlo y guardar un HashMap<String, String> donde almacenes localidad y código (ej: 25 20171022164520), posterior a esto lees el archivo  de texto y por cada linea obtiene el string de la provincia y lo buscas por llave en el Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Su código puede quedar de la siguiente forma

```
public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

    Map<String, String> mapaCodigosProvincia = new HashMap();

    try {
        // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("ruta.txt"));
        // Creamos el objeto de entrada
        DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
        String contenido;
        // Leer el archivo linea por linea

        while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!contenido.equals("")){
                String[] arrayStrings = contenido.split(",");
                mapaCodigosProvincia.put(arrayStrings[0], arrayStrings[1]);
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Cerramos el archivo
        entrada.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
        System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    //Recorremos el arrayList
    for(String nombreArchivo : arrayList){
        String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
        String provincia = separador[0].replace("PDA", "").trim();

        //Obtenemos el nombre de la provincia
        String nombreProvincia = mapaCodigosProvincia.get(provincia);
    }

}
```

Comment: Estimado @isaac el código proporcionado en tu respuesta me a ayudado pero al implementarlo me muestra lo que tengo en el `arraylist` y no en el archivo de texto me explico? Lo que necesito es leer el contenido del `arraylist`, leer el contenido del archivo de texto `.txt` y evaluar el cod de dos digitos que tienen ambos, osea **PDA25** que posee el arraylist con el **25** que contiene el archivo de texto, de ser iguales que muestre la localidad de perteneciente a dicho cod me explico?

Comment: A lo mejor yo me exprese mal en mi pregunta, igualmente tu cod me sirvió pero estoy tratando de hacer eso, comparar los códigos y que muestre la localidad.

Comment: Ok, puedes hacer la implementación al contrario, en el hashMap guardas las provincias y posterior a esto recorres el arrayList.

Comment: justamente eso quiero hacer pero no lo logro hacer, obtengo **arrayindexoutofboundsexception 1** al querer recorrer el archivo .txt

Comment: Si lo que hay en el arrayList son Strings de la forma PDA25_20171022164520 el error se presenta por que en el if `if (arrayStrings[i].substring(0, arrayStrings[i].lastIndexOf(",")).equals(array[j].substring(0, array[j].lastIndexOf(","))))` esta buscando una coma, como no la encuentra retorna `-1` y desde hay inicia a hacer un el `subString();`

Comment: vos me hablas del código que puse en mi pregunta verdad? En ese caso si daría error, lo que deseo realizar es la implementación a revés de lo que brindaste en tu respuesta con hashmap pero no puedo, me da error

Comment: Porque la respuesta que brindaste me muestra lo que coincide con el arraylist, es muy similar a lo que quiero lograr pero a revés, que me muestre las localidades que se encuentran en el archivo `.txt` comparar los cod de dos dígitos del arraylist con el del archivo ej: **25, BUENOS AIRES** el cual pertenece a lo que el archivo y compararlo con **PDA25** que se encuentra en el arraylist.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código, espero le funcione

Comment: La verdad agradezco tu interés y buena predisposición por ayudar, se te agradece de verdad pero no es lo que necesito, ese código me lista solo las provincias, todas las provincias que tengo en mi `.txt` el código tiene que realizar lo mismo pero **solo** que muestre las provincias cuyo dígitos coincidan con los dígitos que tengo en mi arraylist ej: si existen num iguales que me muestre la localidad perteneciente a esos numero. Agradezco tu ayuda imensamente

Comment: Algo parecido a lo que hacía el código de tu primer respuesta pero a revés, en vez de mostrarle los dígitos coincidentes de mi arraylist, liste los dígitos coincidentes de mi archivo txt

Comment: Algo parecido a lo que hacía el código de tu primer respuesta pero a revés, en vez de mostrarle los dígitos coincidentes de mi arraylist, liste los dígitos coincidentes de mi archivo txt

Comment: **EURECA!** Lo e conseguido finalmente! Solo tenia que crear una variable String **keyArray** donde almacene los Núm de dos dígitos que tengo en mi arraylist y compararlo con los que hay en el hashmap donde están cargados los códigos de las provincias de mi archivo de texto lo cual hice  `String[] arrayStrings = contenido.split(",");           mapaCodigosProvincia.put(arrayStrings[0], keyArray);`